# How to get out an httpGet response from a Thread Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http-get

I have this Thread on a Fragment

```
          Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run(){
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet post = new HttpGet("http://www.no798.eu/notizie.php");
            HttpResponse rp = null;
            try {
                rp = hc.execute(post);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                // Server is unavailable
            }
            try {

                String str=EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    trd.start();
```

How i can get out of Thread the EntityUtils String?
If a try java whant a Final one-element array String...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming) but to run it back on UI thread you have to post it back to UI handler ... anyway, AsyncTask is easier to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Handler` in your `Activity` or `Fragment`, and pass the result of the HTTP call to it.

In your `Activity`/`Fragment`:

```
private final static int HANDLER_FROM_HTTP = 1;
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        final int what = msg.what;
        switch(what) {
            case HANDLER_FROM_HTTP:  {
                Bundle b = msg.getDate();
                if (b != null) {
                    String s = b.getString("result");
                    doSomething(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then, in the `run()` method of your `Thread` above:

```
String str=EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
Message msg = pThreadHandler.obtainMessage(HANDLER_FROM_HTTP);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("result", str);
msg.setData(b);
msg.sendToTarget();
```

This will allow you to execute `doSomething()` on the main UI thread to update a `View`, or perform some other action.

Comment: but much easier is to use `final String str` .... and then `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { doSomething(str); } });`(if the code which is starting the thread is inside the Activity)

Comment: True. And, like @Selvin said in the above comment, it's even easier (and probably better) to use an AsyncTask, or Loader.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that runOnUiThread just wrapping code similar to your

Comment: @Selvin you'd have to look at the Android source code to be sure, but it doesn't really matter as they achieve the same thing.